# MySQL Case Statement Issues

Tags: mysql

I have a table shown as below which is a representation of tree.

```
id ---  parentid
 1        NULL
 2        1
 3        1
 4        2
```

Here 1 is the root node and 4,3 are leaf nodes and 2 is intermidiate node. How to write a sql query which prints

```
id ---- type
1        root
2        intermiditae
3        leaf
4        leaf
```

Comment: I would add `id=1 parentid=1` for the root to the data. Query should work with a union of 3 selects for the 3 cases, root, interm and leaf: `select id,'root' as type from data where id=parentid union select ...`. Work on this and get back with your query.

Comment: Yeah , sorry i will edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
SELECT mytable.id, IF(mytable.parent_id IS NULL, 'root',
                      IF(COUNT(children.id) > 0, 'intermediate', 'leaf'))
FROM mytable
LEFT JOIN mytable AS children ON children.parent_id = mytable.id
GROUP BY mytable.id;
```

The "root" is the row for which `parent_id` is `NULL`. Then, counting the number of children is enough to determine if the entry is a leaf or not.

- [Try it online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0c81/1/0)

---

You can also obtain the same result with 3 queries and `UNION`.

```
(SELECT mytable.id, 'root' AS type
 FROM mytable
 WHERE mytable.parent_id IS NULL)
UNION
(SELECT mytable.id, 'intermediate' AS type
 FROM mytable
 JOIN mytable AS children ON children.parent_id = mytable.id
 WHERE mytable.parent_id IS NOT NULL
 GROUP BY mytable.id)
UNION
(SELECT mytable.id, 'leaf' AS type
 FROM mytable
 LEFT JOIN mytable AS children ON children.parent_id = mytable.id
 WHERE children.id IS NULL);
```

- [Try it online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0c81/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

Use a left join to itself to determine existence of children:

```
select id,
  case when parent_id is null then 'root'
    when child is null then 'leaf'
    else 'intermediate' end as type
from mytable
left join (select parent_id parent, max(id) child
    from mytable group by 1) x on parent = id
```